# Random "Interaction has already been acknowledged" errors sometimes

Tags: javascript, discord.js, discord-interactions

I get the error

node:events:515
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged

randomly. At first my code always works, but not the second time. Could this possibly be because the "interactionCreate" event is still running? Don't be surprised, I'm actually German, which is why the strings are often German. Also, the variables such as "d" will be renamed later, they are currently only for me to test the code. If you have any questions about the code, just ask. Some variables are outside this code, but I think they are not relevant for this error

My Code:

```
if(m == "mine"){
        let embed = {
            title: `Mine`,
            description: `Wähle aus was du abbauen möchtest`,
            color: 0xFFFF00,
            thumbnail: {
                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
            },
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer: {
                text: footer,
                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
            },
        }

        let row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(
                    new SelectMenuBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('mine')
                        .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                        .addOptions(
                            {
                                label: 'Eisen',
                                value: 'eisen',
                            },
                        ),
                );
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [row]})
        try {
            client.on("interactionCreate", async (e) => {
                if(e.customId == "mine"){
                    if(e.user.id !== message.author.id) return
    
                    let embed = {
                        title: `Mine`,
                        description: `Dir werden jetzt nacheinander Farben angezeigt, baue die mit gleicher Farbe gekennzeichneten Eisen Buttons ab`,
                        color: 0xFFFF00,
                        thumbnail: {
                            url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                        },
                        timestamp: new Date(),
                        footer: {
                            text: footer,
                            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                        },
                    }

                    
    
                    await e.update({embeds: [embed], components: []})

                    await sleep(2000)

                    await e.deleteReply()

                    await sleep(1000)
    
                    let se = ""
                    let d = 1
                    let see = 0
                    
                    let s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
                    see = see + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)
                    se = se + s.toString()
                    let embed1 = {
                        title: `Mine`,
                        description: `${d}: ${s == 0 ? "" : s == 1 ? "" : s == 2 ? "" : s == 3 ? "" : ""}`,
                        color: 0xFFFF00,
                        thumbnail: {
                            url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                        },
                        timestamp: new Date(),
                        footer: {
                            text: footer,
                            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                        },
                    }
    
                    await e.channel.send({embeds: [embed1]}).then(async (a) => {
                        await sleep(1000)
                        for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++){
                                let s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
                                see = see + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)
                                se = se + s.toString()
                                d = d + 1
                                embed1 = {
                                    title: `Mine`,
                                    description: `${d}: ${s == 0 ? "" : s == 1 ? "" : s == 2 ? "" : s == 3 ? "" : ""}`,
                                    color: 0xFFFF00,
                                    thumbnail: {
                                        url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                    },
                                    timestamp: new Date(),
                                    footer: {
                                        text: footer,
                                        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                    },
                                }
                                await a.edit({embeds: [embed1]})
                            await sleep(1000)
                        }
                        console.log(se)
                        embed1 = {
                            title: `Mine`,
                            description: `Gebe jetzt die Farben nacheinander an`,
                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                            thumbnail: {
                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                            },
                            timestamp: new Date(),
                            footer: {
                                text: footer,
                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                            },
                        }

                        let button1 = new ActionRowBuilder()
                        .addComponents(
                            new ButtonBuilder()
                            .setCustomId("red")
                            .setLabel("Rot")
                            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                            .setEmoji(""),

                            new ButtonBuilder()
                            .setCustomId("green")
                            .setLabel("Grün")
                            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                            .setEmoji(""),

                            new ButtonBuilder()
                            .setCustomId("blue")
                            .setLabel("Blau")
                            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                            .setEmoji(""),

                            new ButtonBuilder()
                            .setCustomId("orange")
                            .setLabel("Orange")
                            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                            .setEmoji(""),

                            new ButtonBuilder()
                            .setCustomId("lila")
                            .setLabel("Lila")
                            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                            .setEmoji("")
                        );
                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: [button1]}).then(r => {
                            let f = ""
                            client.on("interactionCreate", async (inte) => {
                                embed1 = {
                                    title: `Mine`,
                                    description: `Du hast leider daneben geschlagen`,
                                    color: 0xFFFF00,
                                    thumbnail: {
                                        url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                    },
                                    timestamp: new Date(),
                                    footer: {
                                        text: footer,
                                        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                    },
                                }

                                let row2 = new ActionRowBuilder()
                                .addComponents(
                                    new ButtonBuilder()
                                    .setCustomId("red")
                                    .setLabel("Rot")
                                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                                    .setEmoji("")
                                    .setDisabled(true),

                                    new ButtonBuilder()
                                    .setCustomId("green")
                                    .setLabel("Grün")
                                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                                    .setEmoji("")
                                    .setDisabled(true),

                                    new ButtonBuilder()
                                    .setCustomId("blue")
                                    .setLabel("Blau")
                                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                                    .setEmoji("")
                                    .setDisabled(true),

                                    new ButtonBuilder()
                                    .setCustomId("orange")
                                    .setLabel("Orange")
                                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                                    .setEmoji("")
                                    .setDisabled(true),

                                    new ButtonBuilder()
                                    .setCustomId("lila")
                                    .setLabel("Lila")
                                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                                    .setEmoji("")
                                    .setDisabled(true)
                                );

                                if(inte.customId == "red"){
                                    f = f + "0"
                                    if(!se.startsWith(f)){
                                        console.log(f)
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: [row2]})
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if(se == f){
                                        embed1 = {
                                            title: `Mine`,
                                            description: `Du hast erfolgreich ${see} Eisen abgebaut`,
                                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                                            thumbnail: {
                                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                            timestamp: new Date(),
                                            footer: {
                                                text: footer,
                                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                        }
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: []})

                                        Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen = Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen + see
                                        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./userdata.json"), JSON.stringify(Data, null, 4), err =>{
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(inte.customId == "green"){
                                    f = f + "1"
                                    if(!se.startsWith(f)){
                                        console.log(f)
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: [row2]})
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if(se == f){
                                        embed1 = {
                                            title: `Mine`,
                                            description: `Du hast erfolgreich ${see} Eisen abgebaut`,
                                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                                            thumbnail: {
                                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                            timestamp: new Date(),
                                            footer: {
                                                text: footer,
                                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                        }
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: []})

                                        Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen = Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen + see
                                        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./userdata.json"), JSON.stringify(Data, null, 4), err =>{
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(inte.customId == "blue"){
                                    f = f + "2"
                                    if(!se.startsWith(f)){
                                        console.log(f)
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: [row2]})
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if(se == f){
                                        embed1 = {
                                            title: `Mine`,
                                            description: `Du hast erfolgreich ${see} Eisen abgebaut`,
                                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                                            thumbnail: {
                                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                            timestamp: new Date(),
                                            footer: {
                                                text: footer,
                                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                        }
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: []})

                                        Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen = Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen + see
                                        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./userdata.json"), JSON.stringify(Data, null, 4), err =>{
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(inte.customId == "orange"){
                                    f = f + "3"
                                    if(!se.startsWith(f)){
                                        console.log(f)
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: [row2]})
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if(se == f){
                                        embed1 = {
                                            title: `Mine`,
                                            description: `Du hast erfolgreich ${see} Eisen abgebaut`,
                                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                                            thumbnail: {
                                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                            timestamp: new Date(),
                                            footer: {
                                                text: footer,
                                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                        }
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: []})

                                        Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen = Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen + see
                                        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./userdata.json"), JSON.stringify(Data, null, 4), err =>{
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(inte.customId == "lila"){
                                    f = f + "4"
                                    if(!se.startsWith(f)){
                                        console.log(f)
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: [row2]})
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if(se == f){
                                        embed1 = {
                                            title: `Mine`,
                                            description: `Du hast erfolgreich ${see} Eisen abgebaut`,
                                            color: 0xFFFF00,
                                            thumbnail: {
                                                url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                            timestamp: new Date(),
                                            footer: {
                                                text: footer,
                                                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL(),
                                            },
                                        }
                                        await a.edit({embeds: [embed1], components: []})

                                        Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen = Data[message.author.id].Economy.Inventory.Items.Eisen + see
                                        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./userdata.json"), JSON.stringify(Data, null, 4), err =>{
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                await inte.deferUpdate()
                                console.log("Richtig")
                            })
                        })
                    })
                }
                
                return;
            })
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you have an error, try to reduce it to the smallest reproducible example possible, otherwise it's really annoying to answer this type of question and inspect the whole code. Good luck on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned two error:

1. Unknown Interaction
2. Interaction has already been acknowledged

If `Unknown Interaction` then it happens when you reply late to the interaction i.e after 3sec.
&
If `Interaction has already been acknowledged` then it happens when you try to reply the interaction that you already replied.

Comment: Hey, do you know where the 2nd error from my code comes from? And what I would have to change to fix it? The first error was an accident on my part and should not be in the title.

Comment: I think I need to close my "interactionCreate" event, but how do I do that. I have now introduced a console log and it is output 2 times before the bot crashes.

Comment: Sorry for late response but I can't check whole code as it's really big and will be hard to find the code that's giving that error. But as I already mentioned above "You are trying to reply to the interaction that is already replied" and you can fix it by using `.editReply` after you `.reply` any interaction. 
Example:
`interation.reply("Hello discord!")` 
If you do this, then you have to do
`interaction.editReply("Message changed!")`
to change the message of same interaction.